# How to get correct values for normals in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I don’t understand how normals are computed in threejs.

Here is my problem :

I create a simple plane

```
var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 100, 10, 10);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
material.setValues({side: THREE.DoubleSide, color: 0xaabbcc});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(plane, material);
mesh.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);
scene.add(mesh);
```

When I read the normal of this plane, I get (0, 0, 1).
But the plane is parallel to the z axis so the value is wrong.

I tried adding

```
mesh.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
mesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

but I still get the same result.

Did I miss anything ?

How can I get correct values for normals from threejs ?

Thanks.

Comment: Geometry normals are not recomputed after a rotation ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Geometry normals are in object space. To transform them to world space, first make sure the object matrix is updated.

```
object.updateMatrixWorld();
```

(The renderer does this for you in each render loop, so you may be able to skip this step.)

Then, compute the normal matrix:

```
var normalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix3().getNormalMatrix( object.matrixWorld );
```

Now transform the normal to world space like so:

```
var newNormal = normal.clone().applyMatrix3( normalMatrix ).normalize();
```

three.js r.66

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for!! could you ev. help me with translating normals the other way around: world space to local space? (in the end i need a local-world-local2 translation)

Comment: @tomaspolach Please post a question if you need help.

Comment: How do I get "normal" in "normal.clone().applyMatrix3"?

Comment: arpo, normal is a property of a face (maybe vertex too?). In my code I use a raycaster to get an intersect object and then I get the normal as intersect.face.normal